# Return specific value depending on conditions: incorrect number of dimensions

Tags: r, if-statement

```
    A <- structure(list(Column_1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("X.1", "X.2", "X.3", "X.4"), class = "factor"), 
        Column_2 = c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", 
        "seven", "four", "two", "one"), Column_3 = c("C", "C", "C", 
        "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "B")), row.names = c(NA, -10L
    ), class = "data.frame")

    B <- structure(list(Column_3 = structure(c(5L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 
    6L, 1L, 4L, 8L), .Label = c("eight", "five", "four", "nine", 
    "one", "seven", "six", "ten", "three", "two"), class = "factor"), 
        X.1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), X.2 = c(11, 12, 13, 
        14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20), X.3 = c(21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 
        26, 27, 28, 29, 30), X.4 = c(31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 
        38, 39, 40)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

    C <- structure(list(Column_3 = structure(c(5L, 10L, 9L, 3L, 2L, 7L, 
    6L, 1L, 4L, 8L), .Label = c("eight", "five", "four", "nine", 
    "one", "seven", "six", "ten", "three", "two"), class = "factor"), 
        X.1 = c(50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59), X.2 = c(60, 
        61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69), X.3 = c(70, 71, 72, 
        73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79), X.4 = c(80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 
        85, 86, 87, 88, 89)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Above are three dataframes A, B, and C.  Below is one dataframe (D) which is the same as dataframe A, but has an extra column with the answers I am trying to solve for.  So after I run the process, dataframe A should add column 4 from dataframe D.

If dataframe A column 3 is B then use dataframe B for the next step. If dataframe A column 3 is C then use dataframe C for the next step.  Once the correct dataframe has been selected, look at dataframe A column 2.  Match the "value" and highlight the ROW in dataframe C (since C is the dataframe we would be using for this example).  Then go back to dataframe A and look at column 1.  Match the "value" and highlight the COLUMN.  Find the intersecting value and put it is dataframe D column 4.  Rinse and repeat.

I found a solution running ifelse statements, but am getting an error of "Error in Table_1[DF2, DF1] : incorrect number of dimensions". I read from another post that you should put the dataframes into matrices?

```
    Table_1 <-
      ifelse(A$Column_3 == "C", C, B)

    DF1 <- 
      ifelse(A$Column_2 =="one", 1,
             ifelse(A$Column_2 =="two", 2,
                    ifelse(A$Column_2 =="three", 3,
                           ifelse(A$Column_2 =="four", 4,
                                  ifelse(A$Column_2 =="five", 5,
                                         ifelse(A$Column_2 =="six", 6,
                                                ifelse(A$Column_2 =="seven", 7,
                                                       ifelse(A$Column_2 =="eight", 8,
                                                                      ifelse(A$Column_2 =="nine", 9,
                                                                             ifelse(A$Column_2 =="ten", 10, ""))))))))))

    DF2 <- 
      ifelse(A$Column_1 == "X.1", 1 + 1,
             ifelse(A$Column_1 == "X.2", 2 + 1,
                    ifelse(A$Column_1 == "X.3", 3 + 1,
                           ifelse(A$Column_1 == "X.4", 4 + 1, ""))))

    A$Column_4 <- Table_1[DF2, DF1]


    D <- structure(list(Column_1 = c("X.1", "X.2", "X.3", "X.4", "X.5", "X.6", "X.7", "X.8", "X.9", "X.10"), Column_2 = c("one", 
    "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "four", "two", 
    "one"), Column_3 = c("C", "C", "C", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
    "C", "B"), Column_4 = c(50, 61, 72, 34, 5, 85, 66, 73, 51, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Please edit to add sample code. You can also copy and paste current and expected data formats.

Comment: NelsonGon, I found a solution to how to solve my original problem, but am running into another error that I do not know how to fix.  I added my solution to the original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you are planning on stringing together a lot of `ifelse` statements, it would be easier and simpler to use `case_when` instead.  However, for this problem I think this will be much simpler if you wrangle the data from `B` and `C`, where we make it long data and then join with `A`.

This can be done pretty readily with `dplyr` and `tidyr`.  First we'll modify `B` and `C`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

B_mod <- B %>% 
  gather(-Column_3, key = "identifier", value = "Value") %>% 
  mutate(data = "B")

C_mod <- C %>% 
  gather(-Column_3, key = "identifier", value = "Value") %>% 
  mutate(data = "C")
```

Now, we'll combine these modified dataframes into a single, long dataframe.

```
full_mod <- bind_rows(B_mod, C_mod) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character)
```

Finally, we'll match columns from `A` to our newly created `full_mod` dataframe with a `left_join`.  In the `by` argument, columns in `A` are on the lefthand side, while their corresponding columns in `full_mod` are on the right.

```
A %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  left_join(full_mod,
            by = c("Column_1" = "identifier",
                   "Column_2" = "Column_3",
                   "Column_3" = "data"))
```

Which gives us:

```
   Column_1 Column_2 Column_3 Value
1       X.1      one        C    50
2       X.2      two        C    61
3       X.3    three        C    72
4       X.4     four        B    34
5       X.1     five        B     5
6       X.4      six        C    85
7       X.2    seven        C    66
8       X.3     four        C    73
9       X.1      two        C    51
10      X.1      one        B     1
```

#### Edit:

I added a `mutate_if` to ensure that factors are converted to character to improve the `left_join`

Comment: Hello Dave.  I pretty much understand what you are doing here.  Thank you for simplifying my ifelse statements.  I just didn't know how to do it another way.  I ran what you have provided but am getting an error: "Error in nlevels(object) : argument "object" is missing, with no default".

Comment: At what step are you running into the issue?  It's also possible your versions of dplyr/tidyr are out of date

Comment: I run into this issue at thee last step.  My tidry version is 0.8.2 and my dplyr version is 0.7.8

Comment: Hopefully the updated code resolves your issue.  Although I am unable to replicate your error

Comment: That works!  I do get a warning message: "Column `Column_2` / `Column_3` joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector".  Should I be concerned about this error message?

Comment: Great!  You'll see I also modified the `full_mod` dataframe as well with a `mutate_if`.  This should address the warning message, although I don't believe this warning message will be a problem for you as is.

Comment: Perfect that works!  Do you have any idea of why my original code did not work?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the goal was, but your call for `Table_1` creates an unnamed list using the full data frames of `B` and `C`.  `DF1` and `DF2` are then character vectors (that final `ifelse` call that uses `""` instead of `NA` will do that).
So the call `Table_1[DF2, DF1]` is attempting to subset an unnamed list as if it were a dataframe using 2 character vectors.